# How to tell Git that two commits are actually the same in a disjoint history?

Tags: git, version-control, git-svn

I have a Git repo that is clone from another Git repo that is a clone from a giant SVN repo. We can update the other Git repo from SVN and commit from it to SVN, but with another user.

I want to publish my local commits to the SVN repo directly, with my own user.

This is what I tried: I manually created the `git-svn` branch, adding this to `.git/config`

```
[branch "master"]
[svn-remote "svn"]
        url = https://url/to/svn/trunk/repo_name
        fetch = :refs/remotes/git-svn
```

Then `git svn fetch`, downloaded 32k commits.

But I ended up with two disjoint histories:

1. One from Git:

   1. Starting at commit `674c35a` that represents the state of the SVN repo at the point of the original clone.
   2. The branch `master` is always synchronized with SVN (through the other Git repo).
   3. The branch `dev` have our current developments, that should be merged to `master` (usually squashed), and then committed back to the SVN repo.
2. One for the SVN repo:

   1. Starts with the proper initial commit.
   2. It has 30k+ commits.
   3. The commit that Git originally cloned from SVN [`fb1b9c7`] (but only with diff from the previous commits, not the entire repo as a start commit).
   4. Then the same commits (100+) that should be common to `git/origin/master`.

How can I tell Git that the starting commit (`674c35a`) is actually the same as a SVN commit (`fb1b9c7`)? So Git can somehow understand that the commits in `master`, after the clone, are actually the same as `git-svn`?

I have tried to rebase with `--onto`, as explained [here](http://brandon.dimcheff.com/2009/01/04/commit-a-linear-git-history-to-subversion.html), but that wasn't really what I wanted (the commits are not in top of the branch).

Comment: Git + SVN... what's the point?

Comment: SVN is mandatory for this project, but my team wanted to use git (distributed, code review, branches, etc)

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have a method which should work for this in my blog post [Grafting History with Git](http://strangeowl.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/grafting-history-with-git.html) which for the purposes of complying with site rules I'll summarize here :

Current state :

- Two git repos with diverging histories but one origin

Target state :

- One git repo with two branches representing those diverging histories

---

- Convert both histories into Git branches (I think you've already got this)
- Find the point of divergence by comparing logs and seeing when the **tree** hash changes

  - Get a list of the tree-ids and commit-ids on each branch using `git log --reverse --format="%T %H"` and save this to a file
  - Compare the lists to see where the tree hash diverges (I use a diff program that can do columns, you could just use awk and diff though)
- Check out the point of divergence on the target repo branch and make a new branch
- Fetch all the objects from source into target
- For each revision in the original source, create a new revision on target that

  - Is a checkout of the tree of the foreign revision using `git read-tree -um $TREEID`
  - Uses the original commit message using `git commit --reuse-message $ORIGINAL_COMMIT`

Or ... cat your list of tree-id + commit-id into this script.

```
#!/bin/bash
# graft script
while read TREE COMMIT
do
 git read-tree -um $TREE
 git commit --reuse-message $COMMIT
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Your history probably looks something like this:

```
*--*--*--fb1b9c7--*--*--* [git-svn] (version of master from SVN)

         674c35a--*--*--* [master] (version of master from Git)
                         \
                          *--*--*--* [dev]
```

It looks like you have two issues: your Git history doesn't contain the 30k+ commits from the full SVN history, and `dev` is based off the (incomplete) Git history instead of the SVN version.

Since `fb1b9c7` == `674c35a`, you should be able to do:

```
git rebase --onto git-svn master dev
```

My experiments indicate that `git rebase` doesn't care that the target branch (`git-svn`) doesn't have the same history as the base branch (`master`). It also shouldn't matter that SVN only stores diffs, because git-svn will have converted those diffs into real Git commits during the fetch.

Since the histories contain the same contents, you should even be able to do:

```
git checkout dev
git rebase git-svn
```

After that, you can delete `master` and let that tree get garbage-collected later. (If you still need a separate `master` branch, then do `git checkout -b master git-svn` after deleting the original `master`.)

When you said:

> (the commits are not in top of the branch)

I assume that you are referring to commits `fb1b9c7` and `674c35a`. However, it doesn't matter that those commits are buried in the history, because we will choose one (`fb1b9c7`) to use, and let the other be garbage-collected, as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace one commit by another commit, just use `git replace`, like `git replace 674c35a fb1b9c7`.
If you then want to make this permanent, use `git rebase`.